# History behind the choice of letters $h$ and $k$ for the vertex of a parabola?

Tags: math-history, conic-sections

After failing to find a historical explanation for usage of letters $h$ and $k$ for the vertex of a parabola in most relatively recent textbooks in anglosphere, I turn to math.SE.

Is there any historical explanation for usage of these particular letters and if there is, what is it?

Comment: Who exactly uses h and k for the said vertex?

Comment: More or less all textbooks.

Comment: As they say on Wikipedia: The perspective in this question may not represent a worldwide view of the subject. (I looked in a Scandinavian text book and found the vertex to be named $(m,n)$.)

Comment: Question edited to reflect these finds.

Comment: It's not so much that these things are used as the vertex of a parabola. They are used as generic horizontal and vertical shifts. Yes, with parabolas: $y=x^2\to y=(x-h)^2+k$, shifting the vertex $(0,0)$ to $(h,k)$, but also in other places, like $x^2+y^2=1\to(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=1$, shifting a circle's center in the same way. I still don't know why these two particular letters though.

Comment: $h$ stands for $h$orizontal; $k$ stands for verti$k$al?

Comment: I've never heard of this.  Are you sure this phenomenon is more widespread than, say, textbooks published by a single company?

Comment: For some examples see Stitz & Zeager open source mathematics (http://www.stitz-zeager.com/) and Mooculus free textbook (http://mooculus.osu.edu/); I know these are anecdotal evidence, but I still think they're better than just listing books I've got in my shelf (which aren't that numerous anyway).

Answer (score 3):

http://www.latin-dictionary.net/search/latin/kardo

The beauty of vertex form (as opposed to others) is that you can fully control  the "**a**" amplitude (wideness) of the entire parabola, as well as the vertical and horizontal coordinates (h,k) of the vertex -- the center point of the parabola--  in a way that is more easy, interactive and user friendly.

[image]

Before reading this, please know that, the symbols, **"h"** and **"k"** were  originally, only meant for use in the circle equation.

[image]
Making a speculation, one could presume that "***k***" could refer to Latin "kardo". When  roughly translated, this can also mean "axis". But since we're talking about, an axis that moves, I want to say this means, **"hinge"**.

**Which brings us to "h", the axis of symmetry.**

When looking back at the vertex form equation on the top of the page,

if "**h**" were to stand for "**hinge**", it would point out that hinges of doorknobs turn horizontally from the place they are attached to. So in analogy, I suppose that "h"  tells us exactly where the axis of symmetry to the vertex is positioned horizontally. Or (when talking about circle equation) rotated horizontally.

Looking at "k" again,"k" does the same  exact thing as "h", but this time it is where the axis of symmmetry is vertically positioned.

A synonym that carries the same definition as "kardo" is Latin "tenon". This word directly translates into English "tendon". Tendons help organs shift vertically.

Comment: You did a really nice job answering this question; I'd encourage you to expand by answering newer questions :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20170911021602/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57023.html)

"f" and "g" are used to denote functions, "i" and "j" are used for the imaginary unit, "a" - "e" are used for a lot of various different things.  "h" and "k" were just not used for much else.  Thus, someone decided that they would be good to use for vertices/centers.